# Extremely Scientific Sexual Education Material?

Tags: book-recommendation, sexual-reproduction

I'm trying to prepare material for 'the talk' about sex and reproduction. I know there's plenty of great books and resources out there for young readers, which I'll use to start with, but I'm also looking for something ***overbearingly scientific***.

Essentially, I'm looking for an academic-level resource that is as close as possible to a literal play-by-play second-by-second explanation of puberty and the entire reproductive cycle. This is partly to polish my understanding, and to prepare myself for unexpected questions.

For example, it should explain the mechanics that sperm/egg cell(s) use to get around, how sperm penetrates the ovum, the process of breast development, and how they become lactation-ready, how the milk is made, what controls where adult body hair grows, the chemical process leading to feelings of lust, etc.

I was mentally reviewing my knowledge of this the other day and realized I know a lot of 'what' but not 'how' or 'why', so here I am.

Multiple books/resources is fine.

Comment: Why not some high-school biology textbook? Sex-education is a very broad term. Maybe a single book entitled 'sex-education' or 'sexual awareness' etc. would not be enough. You may need to consult basic genetics books and teachers to know topics like why birth successive girl-child can't be depend on the mother. To know about sexually-transmitted disease you may need to consult peoples expert in microbiology and parasitology. To know about menstrual health and hazards of early pregnancy etc. you need to know about human physiology especially, reproductive-biology and endocrinology, as well

Comment: you may take advice from medical professionals, and gynaecology books and nursing training books may add some help. For psychological aspects, you may require training about psychology and counselling and even sociology. Very much interdisciplinery question.

Comment: @Moderators good interdisciplinery question requiring expertise from various fields. Bio or [health](https://health.stackexchange.com) ; which will be more appropriate?